# Filtering based on cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to filter data on workbook 2 `(wsCopy)` based on two cell values in workbook 1 `(wsDest.Worksheets("Overview")`). My goal is to filter anything after the end of month dates in C2 (month) and C3 (year). For example, if January 2022 is chosen, I need the filter to give me February 1, 2022 and on data. The below only gives me data for the exact end of month date (1/31/2022).

```
Sub FilterData()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
   Dim dt As Date
   dt = DateValue("01-" & .Range("C2").Value & "-" & .Range("C3").Value)
End With

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Dummy Data Tests 3.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SECOND DESTINATION TEST")
  
wsCopy.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Format$(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dt, 0), "m/d/yyyy"), Criteria2:="=", _
Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

Moreover, I would also like to filter for any blank cells in the same Field1. I tried making a Criteria2 for "=", but this just results on excluding everything from the filter. Let me know if I can provide any more information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I figured it out! Please see below for the answer:

```
Sub CopyAndPaste()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview")
   Dim dt As Date
   Dim filterdt As Date
   dt = DateValue("01-" & .Range("C2").Value & "-" & .Range("C3").Value)
   filterdt = Format$(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(dt, 0), "m/d/yyyy")
End With

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Dummy Data Tests 3.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SECOND DESTINATION TEST")
  
wsCopy.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">" & filterdt, Criteria2:="", _
Operator:=xlOr

End Sub
```